# Intersection between line and Grid resources

Tags: math, grid

I am using 2-dimensional grid system with X, Y Coordinates. The closest example to what I am using can be found in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270840/find-the-intersection-between-line-and-grid-in-a-fast-manner?tab=active#tab-top).

I can find the length of each segment of the line in each multiplied by the value (could be elevation, or any other number) of the cell.

The question is: I want a mathematical formula which represents this process. If you have any references or any similar works, please refer them to me.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask ?

Comment: Are you suggesting ask the question in this site?

Comment: It is unclear what you think this mathematical formula should look like.  A program is a mathematical formula.  But I like the fact that you researched to find that you weren't the first to ask this kind of question.